# Print every line from a large file where the previous N lines meet specific criteria

Tags: awk

I'd like to print every line from a large file where the previous 10 lines have a specific value in in a specific column (in the example below, column 9 has a value < 1). I don't want to store the whole file in memory. I am trying to use awk for this purpose as follows:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=","}
   {
   for (i=FNR,i<FNR+10, i++) saved[++s] = $0 ; next
   for (i=1,i<s, i++)
       if ($9<1)
   print saved[s]; delete saved; s=0
  }' file.csv
```

The goal of this command is to save the 10 previous lines, then that check that column 9 in each of those lines meets my criteria, then print the current line. Any help with this, or suggestion on a more efficient way to do this, is much appreciated!

Comment: Use `for( .. ;  .. ; .. )` with **semicolons** instead of commas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution for GNU Awk:

**chk_prev_lines.awk**

```
BEGIN { FS=","
        CMP_LINE_NR=10
        CMP_VAL = 1     }

FNR > CMP_LINE_NR {
        ok = 1
        # check the stored values
        for( i = 0; i< CMP_LINE_NR; i++ ) {
          if ( !(prev_Field9[ i ] < CMP_VAL) ) {
             ok = 0
             break # early return
          }
        }
        if( ok ) print
      }

      { # store $9 for the comparison
        prev_Field9[ FNR % CMP_LINE_NR] = $9
      }
```

Use it like this: `awk -f chk_prev_lines.awk your_file`.

**Explanation**

- `CMP_LINE_NR` determines how many values from previous lines are stored
- `CMP_VAL` determines the values used for the comparison
- The condition `FNR > CMP_LINE_NR` takes care, that the first line, whose previous lines are checked, is the one with `CMP_LINE_NR +1`. It is the first with that much previous lines.
- The last Action stores the value `$9`. This Action is executed for all lines.

Comment: Don't use all upper case variable names in awk as it makes them look like builtin variable names and creates the possibility of a clash with a builtin variable name. Also, this may be just a style thing, but it's common that variables are named such that words are separated by underscore `prev_field9` or by a change of case `prevField9` but doing both as in `prev_Field9` looks odd and I THINK would be hard for people to remember to use if/when enhancing the code later which is a particular problem for awk since you don't need to init variables so a mis-spelling just creates a new one.

Answer (score 2):

No need to store anything in memory or do any explicit looping on values. To print the current line if the last 10 lines (inclusive) had a $9 value < 1 is just:

```
awk -F, '(c=($9<1?c+1:0))>9' file
```

Untested of course since you didn't provide any sample input or expected output so check the math but that is the right approach and if the math is wrong then the tweak to fix it is just to change `>9` to `>10` or whatever you need.